# How can i rename laravel controller with command line interface(CLI)?

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I created controller which name is `Home` but I want rename it with `HomeController`. Is it possible in laravel?

Example:

```
class Home extends Controller { }
```

I Want to rename it like

```
class HomeController extends Controller { }
```

I Want to do it with CLI.

Comment: unfortunately you cannot use cli to rename, you have to do it manually. Things to consider while renaming controller : filename,classname, routes, controller injection in another controller.

Comment: which OS are you using? why would you want to do it?

Comment: You can create your own CLI commands very easily as of laravel 5.3 to do this manually

Answer (score 7):

You can't use `artisan`, but you can do it manually. But it's not just a simple rename.

You have to:

1. Rename the PHP file.
2. Edit the PHP file to give the class the new controller name (the class name and the file name must match)
3. Change any code that uses that old class name to use the new class name
4. Edit the autoload files to load the new controller file:

```
vendor/composer/autoload_static.php
vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php
```

Comment: use `composer dump-autoload` instead of editing the composer's autoload files manually to avoid mistakes.

Answer (score 5):

You have to do it manually, there is no any command available to updated controller name.

Answer (score 1):

Make a new Controller with the new Name.

```
php artisan make:controller NewController

or 

php artisan make:controller NewController --resource

//if it is a resource controller
```

Now copy all contents from Old Controller to NewController.

Then edit all routes (in web.php) to that Controller.

Answer (score 1):

**forget CLI** why not try rename the controller using '*AS*'

```
use app\MyController as MyControl;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think doing `composer dump-autoload` this regenerates the files :

- vendor/composer/autoload_static.php
- vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php

Answer (score 0):

You can assess the file using `nano` command or `vi`, it depends on your machine. it basically an editor the enable you to change the content of the file.